# How can I convert a Cons list to a Haskell list without (explicit) recursion?

Tags: haskell

I have the following type: `data ConsList elem = Nil | Cons elem (ConsList elem)`

How can I convert a list of this form into a Haskell list, with the conversion not being recursive?

That is, I want `(Cons 3 (Cons 5 (Cons 7 Nil)))` to convert to `[3,5,7]`, or to `(3:(5:(7:[])))` if you wish, and that without actually using a recursive function.

I don't think using fold is okay since this type doesn't actually have it overloaded and I don't see how I could overload fold without actually having explicit recursion.

Comment: By declaring it `Foldable`, and then apply a `fold` on it.

Comment: The thing is the real data structure isn't exactly like this but slightly more complicated (more similar to `(Object s (Maybe (a, Object)))`). Won't Foldable force me to implement fold myself, and thus make me do explicit recursion?

Comment: _Why_ are you avoiding explicit recursion to process a recursive data structure? Explicit tail recursion is not going to blow your RAM usage, afaict. What is the real problem you're solving?

Comment: Well I'm actually requested to avoid recursion for homework. I hope I don't have to change my current structure to a separate one.

Comment: A trick solution could be redefining `show` for it so that it outputs a string that could be then `read` back as a plain list.

Comment: Trouble again as `show` itself would become recursive and the points would still be deducted. I guess I may ask my teacher for this or submit it with the recursive variant.

Comment: Recursion is really the only means of iteration in Haskell. Even if it's buried deep down in folds and binds, it's still recursion. I would guess that what your homework probably means is hiding recursion somewhere outside your own code. I mean, you could always imitate an imperative list accumulation approach in a `State` monad.

Comment: I think I could use unfoldr really. So I just need to understand how that works

Comment: @9000 Quite the opposite: in Haskell, tail recursion on a lazy data structure is indeed going to blow the RAM usage. Using instead `convert (Cons x xs) = x : convert xs`, without tail recursion, will proceed just fine, in a "streaming" fashion.

Comment: ^^^ a.k.a. "guarded recursion", with recursion being "guarded" by a lazy data constructor such as `(:)`.

Comment: @chi Thankfully for my use case the RAM usage doesn't blow up since the list has much less than 100 elements.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for simple data structures is to simply derive Foldable. Apparently though it didn't seem to work even for this structure, let alone the more complicated one I actually needed.

There is a function `unfoldr`. Its type signature is:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Essentially it takes a function which produces the next element of the list and the remainder.

We would call it like:

```
unfoldr unwrapElem l
```

and `unwrapElem` itself is defined such as:

```
unwrapElem :: (ConsList e) -> Maybe (e, ConsList e)
unwrapElem Nil = Nothing
unwrapElem (Cons el rem) = Just (el,rem)
```

One thing to notice is that there still is recursion, however it is implicit now (within `unfoldr` itself)

Comment: Yes there will definitely be recursion *somewhere*, since both `ConsList` and `[]` are recursive data structures.

Comment: Of course. I did want to point out that only the explicit recursion is removed.